# How to get blocks/grand central dispatch working in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

How do I get blocks/grand central dispatch working in Snow Leopard? It appears that the library is not installed by default: when I try to do `#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>`, I get a library not found error.

I have tried making the source I found here: http://libdispatch.macosforge.org/ but it generated an error (`internal.h:99:27: error: Block_private.h: No such file or directory` + others), but I am not even sure if that is the correct source to use. Any pointers on how to get this to work are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to compile anything special to get `dispatch.h`. In fact, *library not found* implies that it's a linking error, not anything to do with `dispatch.h` itself.

For the record, `dispatch.h` is located at: `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h`

Can we see the exact error message? Something doesn't make sense here.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the project is set to use the 10.6 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the current SDK for your project, because Grand Central Dispatch is only working on Snow Leopard.

Go to *Project > Edit Project Settings > General*

At the bottom of the window you have to change the

*Base SDK for All Configurations:* to `Mac OS X 10.6.`